# How do I retrieve specific data from firebase web

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-realtime-database

json file of firebase is like

```html
{
  "users": {
    "a540678c0fda89f430bfba480ffe6f40146548bad72c199f8536b167fc58455a" : {
      "password" : "2a97516c354b68848cdbd8f54a226a0a55b21ed138e207ad6c5cbb9c00aa5aea",
      "phone" : "+91xxxxxxx",
      "uid" : "demo"
    }
  }
}
```

how do i get value for password, phone and uid using ref().once().then() syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/a540678c0fda89f430bfba480ffe6f40146548bad72c199f8536b167fc58455a");
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  var user = snapshot.val();
  console.log(user.password, user.phone, user.uid);
});
```

Comment: function(snapshot) {} scope isn't working on my system

Comment: What isn't working about it? Can you maybe set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem? It'll be a lot easier to help that way.

Comment: Firebug/firefox console isnt running function(snapshot) {} on my system 
Nodejs was able to run this code